# Java - Big result difference when benchmarking an algorithm in ms and ns

Tags: java

I was performing some test performance on an algorithm and noticed something weird. Maybe I am missing something here.

I first measure the time in milliseconde:

```
long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
x.sort(sortStringInput);
long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
```

and then in nanoseconde:

```
long startTime = System.nanoTime();
x.sort(sortStringInput);
long endTime = System.nanoTime();
```

The results are 437ms qnd 26366ns.

I am calling the same method so how can it be possible to get a result in ns which is way smaller than the one in ms. I know that 1 ms is 1 000 000 ns so 26366 is even smaller than 1 ms...

Thanks,

Comment: Values you get from such short intervals are unreliable. Create a loop and perform the test a couple of thousands of times (if not more!). Then take the average and you'll see the two results will be close. And also what @Cameron Skinner said.

Comment: Not to be rude, but people usually suck at writing benchmarks in Java.  You'll need to show your test harness for us to comment intelligently.  Things like Hotspot compilation can drastically affect tests if you're just running it through once.  Ideally you would run them both, one after the other (and many iterations of each at once), many many times before you start to trust the results.  And then you should be taking an average, discarding outlying results (often due to garbage collection), etc.

Comment: BTW, what platform are you running on? `System.nanoTime` typically gives answers that are multiples of thousands.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Are you sorting the same list twice? The second call will be extremely fast if the list is already sorted.

Comment: You are totally right... How can I do something like this... Should I delete the post?

Comment: @user393381: No, don't delete it! If somebody has the same problem and googles for it, he can find help here.

Comment: @user: Also you were given a correct answer, so you can just accept it and it will be "closed off" (in that nobody will try to answer it)

Comment: Also note that the second time you sort the list, even if it is reset, the code will be all loaded and ready to go.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what platform you're on, `System.nanoTime()` itself can be very slow. You're better off running your benchmark multiple times and measuring the overall duration in miliseconds.

Comment: But they're getting the opposite result.  More time in ms than ns

Comment: @dspyz I know that. The point I'm making (badly) is that it's better to measure a longer time (by looping the benchmark) with a more granular unit, than to try and measure a very short interval, using a measure which doesn't always behave predictably.

Comment: WHile this is true, its also worth nothing that currentTimeMillis() and nanoTime() take the same amount of time on some platforms. Its worth following your suggestion no matter how you measure time.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you run the test for at least 2 seconds before counting any result and run the test for at least 2 seconds and take the average.  The following code prints.

```
Average sort time 116 ms.
Average sort time 117100526 ns.
Average sort time 116 ms.
Average sort time 116530255 ns.
Average sort time 117 ms.
Average sort time 116905977 ns.
```

Code

```
public static void main(String... args) throws IOException {
    String[] strings = new String[100 * 1000];
    for (int i = 0; i < strings.length; i++)
        strings[i] = "" + Math.random();

    int runTimeMS = 2000;
    for (int i = 0; i <= 3; i++) {
        {
            long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
            int count = 0;
            do {
                Arrays.sort(strings.clone());
                count++;
            } while (System.currentTimeMillis() - start < runTimeMS);
            long time = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;
            if (i>0) System.out.println("Average sort time " + time / count + " ms.");
        }
        {
            long start = System.nanoTime();
            int count = 0;
            do {
                Arrays.sort(strings.clone());
                count++;
            } while (System.nanoTime() - start < runTimeMS * 1000L * 1000L);
            long time = System.nanoTime() - start;
            if (i>0) System.out.println("Average sort time " + time / count + " ns.");
        }
    }
}
```